# Why is a lock required here?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I'm looking at an example on p. 40 of Stephen Cleary's book that is

```
// Note: this is not the most efficient implementation. 
// This is just an example of using a lock to protect shared state. 
static int ParallelSum(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    object mutex = new object();
    int result = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(source: values, 
       localInit: () => 0, 
       body: (item, state, localValue) => localValue + item, 
       localFinally: localValue => 
       {
            lock (mutex)
                result += localValue;
       });
   return result;
}
```

and I'm a little confused why the `lock` is needed. Because if all we're doing is summing a collection of `int`s, say `{1, 5, 6}`, then we shouldn't need to care about the shared sum `result` being incremented in any order.

```
(1 + 5) + 6 = 1 + (5 + 6) = (1 + 6) + 5 = ...
```

Can someone explain where my thinking here is flawed?

I guess I'm a little confused by the body of the method can't simply be

```
int result = 0;
Parallel.ForReach(values, (val) => { result += val; }); 
return result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `result += localValue;` is really saying `result = result  + localValue;` You are both reading and updating a resource(variable) shared by different threads. This could easily lead into a Race Condition. `lock`makes sure this statement at any given moment in time is accessed by a single thread.

Answer (score 10):

Operations such as addition are not *atomic* and thus are not thread safe. In the example code, if the lock was omitted, it's completely possible that two addition operations are executed near-simultaneously, resulting in one of the values being overridden or incorrectly added. There is a method that *is* thread safe to increment integers: `Interlocked.Add(int, int)`. However, since this isn't being used, the lock is required in the example code to ensure that exactly one non-atomic addition operation at most is completed at a time (in sequence and not in parallel).

Comment: I think its assignment operator that causes the problem. not the addition it self.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Also not quite right.  Both the assignment and the addition are each independently atomic.  What *isn't* atomic is the increment, which is composed of a read, an addition, and then an assignment.  Each three operation is 100% atomic, but *all three together* are not atomic.

Answer (score 7):

Its not about the order in which 'result' is updated, its the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) of updating it, remember that operator `+=` is not atomic, so two threads may not see the udpate of another's thread before they touch it

Comment: That seems so strange to me that a CPU would even allow this collision to occur. When I write C#, I never feel like I have to think about possible hardware-level bugs. I guess I should be.

Comment: Please do! It's not much different from, say C or C++

Comment: @user7127000 It's not a *bug*, it's an essential feature.  If the CPU weren't allowed to re-order operations then your computer would be hundreds of not thousands of times slower than it is.  The cost of those many orders of magnitude of speed is that shared state between threads is *extremely* difficult to deal with, so much so that you should avoid doing so at all costs, including in your example here, as your code would be much faster if run on a single thread, rather than with several.

Comment: @Servy, your comment is absolutely correct except that instruction reordering has nothing to do with race conditions.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Well, it's not the *only* source of race conditions.  It's certainly a relevant one to this context.